# How to add an image to Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have already done everything on this site of my app, but I wanted to add an image after I did my code to put a gradient in the background. Now when I try to add an image, everything (color of gradient and background) goes to the image instead, so I then have a white background and an image with these colors instead of the original image.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:local_food_vrhnika/sidebar.dart';
import 'package:local_food_vrhnika/style/style.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: rdecaDva,
        shadowColor: Colors.black,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                children: [
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'Local',
                  style:
                      naslov(textStyle: TextStyle(color: tekst, fontSize: 25))),
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'food',
                  style: naslov(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(color: oranznaDva, fontSize: 20))),
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'Vrhnika',
                  style:
                      naslov(textStyle: TextStyle(color: tekst, fontSize: 25)))
            ])),
        /*leading: IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.food_bank),
          onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
        ),*/
      ),
      drawer: SideDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [oranzna!, oranznaDva!, rdecaDva!])),
          /*child: Container(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/earth.png'),
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          ),*/
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you changes in **pubspec.yaml** file for image asset?

Comment: add the code in the right way it helps you more and add pubspec.yaml also

Comment: I don't know why the code doesn't form properly

Answer (score 0):

Please add pubspec.YAML file when you insert an image in asset you should start the app from scratch delete the app and run again the app if still your image is not showing please see your pubspec file at there see asset pathand match with your container path